# How can I specify the scroll amount of scrollLineDown and scrollLineUp in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to set the number of lines for `scrollLineDown` and `scrollLineUp`? The default for my VS Code version is a single line, however I'd like to increase that.

Comment: create a key bonding to the `runCommands` command and repeat the command you want multiple times, you can use the same key bind combo as the original key bind

Comment: related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70561889/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45615529/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, no. I'm not aware of a setting to control this. Actually, I'd suggest to look in the direction of keybindings, but even that is a dead end right now. At least- for the two commands you mentioned. The related source code is in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/31e5940fb0f424c89474f4c967be9564a1e793a8/src/vs/editor/browser/coreCommands.ts#L1514. The `args` does not take anything to specify number of lines. Though it looks like it wouldn't be hard at all to implement- just define a type for the number of lines like there is for the `cursorMove` command, and then pass those arguments in the call to `EditorScroll.runCoreEditorCommand`.

I'd suggest that you [raise a feature request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.